# How do I find the detail information on LS(Layout Shift) in my Web Performance panel of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I tried to use Performance panel to capture a series steps of using my web page.

However, I didn't notice any LS, though I was still told that I encountered a "LS" at 647ms.

But I couldn't find any more information on this.

How could I do to find out more?

[image]

Comment: Click the green bars with 50.0 ms and 16.7 ms to compare the screenshot of this frame with the next frame and find what's changed.

Comment: Thanks and I tried. However, I couldn't find any difference between the two screenshots. Is there any place else that I could find more information, like the DOM element's selector or how big CLS score it contributed to.